# Hiding parts before the page components loads

Tags: javascript, css, rendering

The very unpleasant situation arises when the page loads before some parts (fonts, necessary css files) are loaded.

I see on some sites, they hide some parts before the page components loads.

For example:
[image]

I don't want to put a preloader in the page. Is there just a tactic or any other solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

These pages use a javascript framework such Angular, React, or Vue.
They use something called a lifecycle hook. I'm most familiar with Vue.js, but there are different ones depending on when they are called/what is loaded.
They more than likely use a before mounted & mounted lifecycle hook which performs actions until an item is fully loaded, then performs different actions.

If you don't use a library, and are looking to - I'd recommend Vue.js ecause you don't have to install/learn node.js to use it on a page, only need a CDN, and the link I used below will show you how to prevent your page elements from being viewed before they are loaded.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html